# Are maximal intervals of open nonempty sets always equal?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $O\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open nonempty interval. Define for every  $x\in O$:
$$a_x = \inf\{a\in\mathbb{R}\mid(a,x]\subset O\}$$
$$b_x = \sup\{b\in\mathbb{R}\mid[x,b)\subset O\}$$
$$I_x = (a_x, b_x)$$

Now let $x,y\in O$. Then it seems to me that we have three cases:
$$x=y \implies I_x = I_y$$
$$x<y \implies I_x = I_y$$
$$x>y \implies I_x = I_y$$

1. Is this correct? Is there any case in which $I_x \neq I_y$?
2. Moreover is it correct to say that $O=I_x$ $\forall x\in O$?

Comment: $I_x$ is really just the largest open interval in $O$ containing $x$. If $O$ is an interval, your results follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0, 1)\cup (2, 3)$, $x={1\over 2}$, $y={5\over 2}$.

(Do you want $O$ to be an "open *set*" or "open *interval*"?)

Comment: For open *intervals* it is correct that each $I_x$ (for $x\in O$) is all of $O$ - this is the statement that *intervals are connected*. This actually requires proof. For example, in the space of rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, intervals are *not* connected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still rusty with proper terminology. I did mean to say "open interval"

Comment: In that case the statement is correct, but there's a much more direct proof. Fixing $x\in O=(a, b)$, we can just directly show $a_x=a$ and $b_x=b$.